# How to take derivative of matrix inside integrate $\frac {\partial \int |A^TG(x)-B^TJ(x)|^2 H(x)\,dx}{\partial A}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, numerical-methods, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

I have a function as following

$$F=\int |A^TG(x)-B^TJ(x)|^2 H(x)\,dx+\lambda_1 A^2+\lambda_2 B^2$$

where 
$A^T$ is transpose of vector $A$. $A$ is a column vector such as
$A=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        a_1 \\
        a_2 \\
        ... \\
        a_n \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$; 
$B=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        b_1 \\
        b_2 \\
        ... \\
        b_n \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$;
$A^TG(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} a_i G_i $

$G=[G_1...G_i..G_n],J=[J_1...J_i..J_n]$, in which $G_i$ is matrix $n\times n$ and $H(x)$ is [Heaviside](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) smoothing function. Note that  given $G,J,H$

**However, How to find the derivative of these above function?**

$$\frac {\partial F}{\partial A}=?$$
$$\frac {\partial F}{\partial B}=?$$
This is my trying

$$\frac {\partial F}{\partial A}=2\int G(x)(A^TG(x)-B^TJ(x)) H(x)\,dx+2\lambda_1 A=0$$

Answer (score 2):

Since {$G,J$} are third-order tensors, I prefer to write explicit dot products in expressions involving them.

Let $M_a = G\cdot A$ and $M_b = J\cdot B$ and $q = \|M_a-M_b\|^2_F$.

Then the function and its partial derivative are
$$\eqalign{
 F &= \lambda_1\|A\|^2 + \lambda_2\|B\|^2 + \int q(x)\,H(x)\,dx \cr\cr
 \frac {\partial F}{\partial A} &= 2\,\lambda_1 A + \frac{\partial}{\partial A}\int q(x)\,H(x)\,dx \cr
 &= 2\,\lambda_1 A + \int \frac {\partial q} {\partial A}\,H(x)\,dx \cr
}$$
Now we need the differential / derivative of $q$ 
$$\eqalign{
  q &= (M_a-M_b):(M_a-M_b) \cr\cr
 dq &= 2\,(M_a-M_b):dM_a \cr
    &= 2\,(M_a-M_b):G\cdot dA \cr\cr
 \frac {\partial q} {\partial A} &= 2\,(M_a-M_b):G \cr
   &= 2\,(G\cdot A-J\cdot B):G \cr
}$$
The final result is
$$\eqalign{
 \frac {\partial F}{\partial A} &= 2\,\lambda_1 A + 2\,\int (G\cdot A-J\cdot B):G\,H(x)\,dx \cr
}$$

This result differs from yours because the presence of the double-dot (aka Frobenius) product.

A similar result holds for the $B$ vector.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like inner product. Do you think can I find $A$ and $B$ from these equations ∂F/∂A =0 and ∂F/∂B  =0